# Hashing files with python

Tags: python, hash

I'm writing a python script which should look for all the files with the same content in the cwd. My idea is to use hash functions, but when I run the script every file gets a different digest even though they are copies, which doesn't happen if I compute them on the terminal. I just can't figure out where the problem is. Here's the code

```
import sys
import os
import hashlib
from collections import defaultdict

blocksize = 65536

def hashfile(file, hasher):
    buf = file.read(blocksize)
    while len(buf)>0:
        hasher.update(buf)
        buf = file.read(blocksize)
    #print hasher.hexdigest()
    return hasher.hexdigest()

def main():
    dir = os.getcwd()
    files = os.listdir(dir)
    dict = defaultdict(list)
    l = []
    hasher = hashlib.sha256()

    for file in files:
        hash = hashfile(open(file, 'rb'), hasher)
        l.append((hash, file))

    for k, v in l:
        dict[k].append(v)

    for k in dict.items():
        print k


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a single `hasher` for all files and it's be updating accumulatively. When you are dealing with the second file, you get a digest of the first and second file.

```
#hasher = hashlib.sha256()

    for file in files:
        hasher = hashlib.sha256()
        hash = hashfile(open(file, 'rb'), hasher)
        l.append((hash, file))
```

Move the `hasher = hashlib.sha256()` line to the for loop.

I think it's better to move `hasher = hashlib.sha256()` to the `hashfile` function:

```
def hashfile(file):
    hasher = hashlib.sha256()
    buf = file.read(blocksize)
    #original code here
```

It will make the code more clear.